# copy a substring from string and to print the length of substring

Tags: python, substring

I want to take input from the user for an ip address and want to print out the no.segments by extracting "."(dots) from the input and copying  that"."(dots) to new string and print out the length using python

```
Ip_address = input('enter an ip address')
segment = ''
for i in range(0, len(Ip_address)):
    if Ip_address[i] in '.':
        print(Ip_address[i],end='')
        segment = segment+Ip_address[i]

print(segment)
print(len(segment))
```

Comment: What is your definition of _segment_? Your source code currently prints each dot in the ip address, and then print all dots (i.e. **always** print 6 dots given a proper ip address) and print 3, which, once again, **always** prints 3.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are asking. But you can use the split method.

```
Ip_address = "192.168.1.1"
octets = Ip_address.split(".") #['192', '168', '1', '1']
print(len(octets))
```

then you can do whatever you want with the segments

Check out some documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Comment: thank u so much i want to learn about python would u suggest me something if i want to learn from scratch

Comment: @sairaj there's a bunch of resources in the internet. Here are some few
Google has a class -  [Google Developer](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/),
Youtube (has a ton) - [sentdex](https://www.youtube.com/user/sentdex),
Google will be your friend :^)